# firebase hosting using .env for api key showing error > index.cjs.js:536 Uncaught FirebaseError: projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options

Tags: firebase

i am using firebase hosting and put my firebase api key in .env. its works on localhost but when I deploy to the firebase hosting URL it keep showing the error below:

> index.cjs.js:536 Uncaught FirebaseError: projectId must be a string in
> FirebaseApp.options